# useState of React function component

Tags: reactjs

There are `n` items the user can vote on.
There are two React states:

- `votes` is an array of the user's votes on every item.

  const [votes, setVotes] = useState({});
- `voteChanges` indicates how many times the user changed their votes on any of the items.

  const [voteChanges, setVoteChanges] = useState(0);

We have a database listener defined in a `useEffect`. When votes are added/changed in the database, the listener gets called. We need the state `votes` to compare every new vote with its previous value in `votes` to decide whether to increment `voteChanges`. However, we cannot define `votes` as a dependency in `useEffect`, otherwise we will end up in an infinite loop. To get access to the current value of `votes`, we use its functional update. Is it okay to call `setVoteChanges` inside the functional update of `setVotes`? If no, why, and how would you solve this problem?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    databaseListener((changes) => {
      setVotes((oldVotes) => {
        const oVotes = { ...oldVotes };
        for (let change of changes) {
          const itemId = change.id;
          const newVote = change.vote;
          if (oVotes[itemId] !== newVote) {
            setVoteChanges(oldCount => oldCount + 1);
          }
          oVotes[itemId] = newVote;
        }
        return oVotes;
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tracking-vote-changes-x3jhwj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, firstly, you need to make sure the `useEffect` here run only once as you dont need to register to the `databaseListener` every time. Secondly, you need to keep in mind the fact that state changes will result in re-renders, so its better to calculate `voteChange` in a variable and then apply it once. Check the snippet below.

```
useEffect(() => {

    databaseListener((changes) => {

      let voteChanges = 0;

      setVotes((oldVotes) => {
        const oVotes = { ...oldVotes };
        for (let change of changes) {
          const itemId = change.id;
          const newVote = change.vote;
          if (oVotes[itemId] !== newVote) {
            voteChanges++;
          }
          oVotes[itemId] = newVote;
        }
        return oVotes;
      });

      setVoteChanges(oldCount => oldCount + voteChanges); // rather than having to update it each time, just update it once because state changes can result in re-renders

    });

  }, []); // you just need this to run once to register the listener, so add []
```